# Android: onTouchEvent() and onClick events

Tags: android, button, touch

I have a project in which I have overridden onTouchEvent() and register taps and moves through it. I also have buttons on the screen. I'm trying to connect methods to the buttons ie:

```
public void onButtonClick(View view) {
    System.out.println("Here");
}
```

I can connect the method to the button, and the connection appears in the xml:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="onButtonClick"
    android:text="Button"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="89dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="139dp" />
```

But the button click does not appear to be registered. Is it because I'm also overriding onTouchEvent()? If so should I be registering clicks through MotionEvents? If so, what's a clean way to differentiate clicks coming from multiple buttons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But the button click does not appear to be registered. Is it because
>   I'm also overriding onTouchEvent()?

Yes. When `onTouch()` method returns `true`, Android will consider the event has been consumed and will not pass it on to the other various touch handlers (I think it includes the `onClickListener`).

> If so should I be registering clicks through MotionEvents?

You can do that. Or depending on your condition, simply return `false` from the method and let onClickListener do the job.

> If so, what's a clean way to differentiate clicks coming from
>   multiple buttons?

`onTouch(final View v, final MotionEvent event)`

As you can see the onTouch() method has `View` type as parameter. You can check the Id of view by getting `v.getId()` and compare this id with the Button's Id, which you are expecting. You can do as follows:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(final View v, final MotionEvent event) {
    if(v.getId()==R.id.button1){
        //Click is coming from Button with id button1 (specified in layout.xml as android:id="@+id/button1"). 
        //Do something for click
    }
    ...
}
```